# cyberscan.io: Do something against scanning?

Tags: malware, port-scanning

I receive a lot of 404 from cyberscan.io:

```
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /cgi/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /mail/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /test/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /ws/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /admin/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /db/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /inc/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
34.159.13.2 - - [11/Aug/2022:17:32:18 +0200] "GET /sql/en/index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 522 "-" "cyberscan.io"
```

cyberscan.io looks like a company, not just a script from unknown source.

Is there anything which I can do against it?

There are several perspectives: Do something against via law or via technical solution.

Comment: contact the owner with a deny letter...

Comment: There's always a lot of "background noise" being generated by bots scanning random ip-ranges and trying for known vulnerabilities and exploits. It's a fact of modern digital life and you see evidence of that in your log files.
Keep your systems patched and up-to-date and learn to live with that. Or configure a fail2ban rule and block IP's that generate a lot of 404's

Comment: Replace "or" with "and" in the previous comment. You have to apply latest patches and use fail2ban.